# How can you find all unbalanced parens in a string in linear time with constant memory?

Tags: algorithms

I was given the following problem during an interview:

> Gives a string which contains some mixture of parens (not brackets or braces-- only parens) with other alphanumeric characters, identify all parens that have no matching paren.
>
> For example, in the string ")(ab))", indices 0 and 5 contain parens that have no matching paren.

I put forward a working O(n) solution using O(n) memory, using a stack and going through the string once adding parens to the stack and removing them from the stack whenever I encountered a closing paren and the top of the stack contained an opening paren.

Afterwards, the interviewer noted that the problem could be solved in linear time with constant memory (as in, no additional memory usage besides what's taken up by the input.)

I asked how and she said something about going through the string once from the left identifying all open parens, and then a second time from the right identifying all close parens....or maybe it was the other way around. I didn't really understand and didn't want to ask her to hand-hold me through it.

Can anyone clarify the solution she suggested?

Comment: We may need some clarification from you first. Is the first parens or the second parens in "(()" considered unbalanced? Is the last parens or the second to last parens in "())" considered unbalanced? Or is it enough to identify any set of parens with least cardinality such that removing them will leave the remaining parens balanced? Or something else? Or is this part of the interview so that an answer can just put forward any justifiable specification?

Comment: I would say it doesn't matter, up to you. Remove any set that leaves the remainder balanced.

Comment: Then remove them all ;P

Comment: @Veedrac, of course (as you know) the poster forgot the word 'minimal' in "Remove any *minimal* set …."

Comment: I didn't "forget it," per se, but rather left it out because it didn't seem like an important specification to me since there's only one set that can be removed to make it balanced, *besides* "all of them" which is of course defeating the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: "constant memory" means you can take C bytes of memory where C is a constant. It could be that C is 3GB, that's still constant space. Just recall that the size of the input is unbounded.

Comment: @temporary_user_name, it is not true in general that there's only one set that can be removed.  For example, from `()()())` one could remove, say, the first two parentheses and the last one, or all parentheses *but* the first two, or any number of other subsets.  That's why 'minimal' probably belongs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since this comes from a programming background and not a theoretical computer science exercise, I assume that it takes $O(1)$ memory to store an index into the string. In theoretical computer science, this would mean using the RAM model; with Turing machines you couldn't do this and you'd need $\Theta(\log(n))$ memory to store an index into a string of length $n$.

You can keep the basic principle of the algorithm that you used. You missed an opportunity for a memory optimization.

> using a stack and going through the string once adding parens to the stack and removing them from the stack whenever I encountered a closing paren and the top of the stack contained an opening paren

So what does this stack contain? It's never going to contain `()` (an opening parenthesis followed by a closing parenthesis), since whenever the `)` appear you pop the `(` instead of pushing the `)`. So the stack is always of the form `)…)(…(` — a bunch of closing parentheses followed by a bunch of opening parentheses.

You don't need a stack to represent this. Just remember the number of closing parentheses and the number of opening parentheses.

If you process the string from left to right, using these two counters, what you have at the end is the number of mismatched closing parentheses and the number of mismatched opening parentheses.

If you want to report the positions of the mismatched parentheses at the end, you'll need to remember the position of each parenthesis. That would require $\Theta(n)$ memory in the worst case. But you don't need to wait until the end to produce output. As soon as you find a mismatched closing parenthesis, you know that it's mismatched, so output it now. And then you aren't going to use the number of mismatched closing parentheses for anything, so just keep a counter of unmatched opening parentheses.

In summary: process the string from left to right. Maintain a counter of unmatched opening parentheses. If you see an opening parenthesis, increment the counter. If you see a closing parenthesis and the counter is nonzero, decrement the counter. If you see a closing parenthesis and the counter is zero, output the current index as a mismatched closing parenthesis.

The final value of the counter is the number of mismatched opening parentheses, but this doesn't give you their position. Notice that the problem is symmetric. To list the positions of mismatched opening parentheses, just run the algorithm in the opposite direction.

Exercise 1: write this down in a formal notation (math, pseudocode or your favorite programming language).

Exercise 2: convince yourself that this is the same algorithm as [Apass.Jack](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/103020), just explained differently.

Comment: Oh very good Gilles, very well explained. I understand perfectly now. It has been quite a few years since I got an answer from you on one of my questions.

Comment: "If you want to report the positions of the mismatched parentheses at the end, you'll need to remember the position of each parenthesis." Not quite. Linear time doesn't mean single pass. You can do a second pass to find any brackets in the mismatched side and mark them.

Comment: For the last step, you don't have to run it in reverse, you can simply mark the last N "(" as mismatches.

Comment: @MooingDuck That doesn't work. E.g. `(()`.

Comment: While I really like this answer, something keeps bothering me about it. That something is "I somehow need to remember the position  And I think the issue I have with it is : how do you "output the current index" without consuming memory (or a quite specific context where your outputs are consumed in such a way that the order w-of your outputs doesn’t matter).

Comment: @Édouard In the [RAM model](https://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBA77/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK/NODE12.HTM), it takes $O(1)$ memory to store the current index and $O(1)$ time to increment after processing one character of the input. The problem statement doesn't constrain the output format, so the order in which the indices are reported is whatever is convenient.

Comment: @Gilles I don't know much about the RAM model, and that's probably the source of my confusion. What do you mean by "outputing" an index? Writing in a particular place in memory? Do you the index as a single integer to write it in memopry (in which case, how and how how costly is it)? Or does the RAM model include an "output" instruction and we leave it at that?

Comment: @Édouard You could write the output to certain designated memory cells (e.g. use the even-numbered memory cells for computation and the odd-numbered ones as output, optionally with the constraint of not reading from output cells), or use a separate output instruction. Either way outputting one index takes one unit of time.

Comment: @Gilles Wouldn't that require 0(n) memory?

Comment: @Édouard You have to put the output _somewhere_. If you define the output as memory locations, then you shouldn't count those locations as part of the memory usage of the program. (Remember that these are locations that the program isn't allowed to read from.) If you define the output as a special instruction, then it doesn't occupy any memory.

Answer (score 8):

Since we can just ignore all alphanumeric characters, we will assume the string contains only parentheses from now on. As in the question, there is only one kind of parenthesis, "()".

If we keep removing balanced parentheses until no more balanced parentheses can be removed, all remaining parentheses must look like like "))…)((…(", which are all unbalanced parentheses. This observation suggests that we should find first that turning point, before which we have unbalanced closing parentheses only and after which we have unbalanced opening parentheses only.

Here is the algorithm. In a nutshell, it computes the turning point first. Then it outputs extra closing parenthesis, scanning the string from the start to the right until the turning point. Symmetrically, it outputs extra opening parenthesis, scanning from the end to the left until the turning point.

---

Let `str` be the string as an array of characters, whose size is $n$.

Initialize `turning_point=0, maximum_count=0, count=0`. For each `i` from `0` to `n-1` do the following.

1. If `str[i] = ')'`, add 1 to `count`; otherwise, subtract 1.
2. If `count > maximum_count`, set `turning_point=i` and `maximum_count=count`.

Now `turning_point` is the index of the turning point.

Reset `maximum_count=0, count=0`. For each `i` from `0` to `turning_point` do the following.

1. If `str[i] = ')'`, add 1 to `count`; otherwise, subtract 1.
2. If `count > maximum_count`, set `maximum_count = count`. Output `i` as the index of an unbalanced closing parenthesis.

Reset `maximum_count=0, count=0`. For each `i` from `n-1` to `turning_point+1` downwards do the following.

1. If `str[j] = '('`, add 1 to `count`; otherwise, subtract 1.
2. If `count > maximum_count`, set `maximum_count = count`. Output `i` as the index of an unbalanced opening parenthesis.

---

It is clear that the algorithm runs in $O(n)$ time and $O(1)$ auxiliary memory and $O(u)$ output memory, where $u$ is the number of unbalanced parentheses.

---

**If we analyzed the algorithm above, we will see that, in fact, we do not need to find and use the turning point at all.** The nice observation that all unbalanced closing parentheses happens before all unbalanced opening parentheses can be ignored although interesting.

### Here is [code in Python](https://repl.it/@Apass_Jack/unbalancedparenthesecs103018).

Just hit "run" to see several test results.

---

**Exercise 1.** Show that the above algorithm will output a set of parentheses with the least cardinality such that the remaining parentheses are balanced.

**Problem 1.** Can we generalize the algorithm to the case when the string contains two kinds of parentheses such as "()[]"? We have to determine how to recognize and treat the new situation, the interleaving case, "([)]".

Comment: Lol, exercise 1 and problem 1, cute. The logic of the algorithm you've described is surprisingly hard to visualize. I would have to code this out tomorrow to get it.

Comment: It looks like I missed the rather obvious but most important explanation. The logic is, in fact, very simple. First, we output each extra opening parenthesis. Once we have passed the turning point, we output each extra closing parenthesis. Done.

Comment: Finding unbalanced opening parentheses is incorrect. I.e. if your arr is "())", p is 2 and p+1 falls outside of the arr boundary. Just an idea - to find unbalanced opening parentheses you could reverse arr and use part of algorithm to find unbalanced closing parentheses (of course, with reversely adapted indexes).

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric Exactly because $p+1$ falls outside of the boundary, there is no unbalanced opening parentheses in "())".

Comment: Took me a bit to understand this, but I like it, it's pretty clever.. and works at least for every case I have thought